# 2002 Hyundai Elantra

Tags: electrical, hyundai, elantra

I made a down payment to purchase a 2002 Hyundai Elantra and while viewing the car when the battery was disconnected with the car running the car died. Does that mean it's the alternator? Because if I'm not mistaken that would be the only way that would happen. But the tow yard I'm purchasing it from claims that it's something electronic with the car's computer from the battery being dead. Is that possible or am I being treated as a fool?

Comment: As with anything, if you feel you're getting cheated, there's a good chance you are. Get your down payment back and go someplace else, is MHO.

Comment: The car died electrically? As in the battery drained and you couldn't restart the car? On that year Elantra the ECM doesn't have anything to do with the charging circuit. If the car stalled and could be restarted right away than they weren't lying. If it's a ECM issue or not is another question.

Comment: What by you mean "remove the battery"?  Was this an additional battery used to jump start the car or was it the actual battery in the car?

Answer (score 1):

If the cars battery is physically disconnected after the engine is started and it dies then it is definitely the alternator, its job is to provide electrical power to run the engine and recharge the battery. I'd get your down payment back because the tow yard is obviously duping you. Who knows what else they may try and snow you about. Good luck.